# [Typescript]: How to use namespaced value in type?

Tags: typescript

I have following module:

**a.ts**

```
export namespace METHODS {

    export const GET = 'get';

    export const POST = 'post';

    export const PUT = 'put';

    export const DELETE = 'delete';

}
```

**b.ts**

```
import { METHODS } from './a.ts';

export interface Route {
    method: METHODS.GET | METHODS.POST;
}
```

This is not working, and i got error:

`Namespace '"a".METHODS' has no exported member 'GET'`

Am i wrong about the usage? `Typescript` version i used is: `2.1.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use them directly as types and as values then the following will work cleanly

```
export namespace METHODS {

  export const GET = 'get';

  export type GET = typeof GET;

  export const POST = 'post';

  export type POST = typeof POST;

  export const PUT = 'put';

  export type PUT = typeof PUT;

  export const DELETE = 'delete';

  export type DELETE = typeof DELETE;
}
```

Comment: This is really i want, thanks @Aluan Haddad. But this way seems a bit weird, right? ^^

Comment: Yeah it's a bit strange :] but it's easy to consume from an API perspective. There are many issues on the TypeScript repo requesting string enumerations. I think it's likely that there will be a more elegant way to express this sort of thing in the future but it will probably be an application of a more generic higher-order type construct in a future version of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Because Const is not a Type and you canot use const as type. You can exchange const for type if it does not broke another part of your app.

```
export namespace METHODS {
  //export const GET = 'get';
    export type GET = 'get';
    export type POST = 'post';
    export type PUT = 'put';
    export type DELETE = 'delete';
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks @Misaz. It reminds me that i need to read more docs about ts^^

Comment: `Because Const is not a Type and you canot use const as type` but it has a type if you use `typeof`. Also, names in the Type and Value spaces can and do overlap all of the time.